# ASP.NET Core MVC - rendering a view within RenderBody()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

`_Layout.cshtml` contains `RenderBody()` which generates the content from the view at `Index.cshtml`.

`Index.cshtml` has a large script loading jstree with jQuery.

```
$('#tree').jstree({
        "plugins": ["search", "wholerow", "dnd", "contextmenu", "massload", "search", "types"],
        'core': {
            "check_callback": true, // enable all modifications, tweak for rules.
            'data': {
                'url': function (node) {
                    return node.id === '#' ? "/Home/GetRoot" : "/Home/GetChildren/" + node.id;
                },
                'data': function (node) {
                    return { 'id': node.id };
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

An event on `changed.jstree` captures information about the node that is selected. 
I want to render a view below the tree that contains an editable form allowing to perform CRUD operations on the tree.

```
$('#tree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetNodeInformation/" + data.selected,
            data: '{id: "' + data.selected + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response['node_type'] == 'Portfolio') {
                    $('#nodeinfo').load('@Url.Action("GetPortfolioDetails", "Portfolio")');
                }
                console.log(response['node_type'])
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Rendering the tree and the event on it works well, I believe this is because the `RenderBody` is functioning as it should.

But the moment I call

```
$('#nodeinfo').load('@Url.Action("GetPortfolioDetails", "Portfolio")');
```

The whole page gets rendered again within that div.

Question - since my app is a single page application, how to properly manage placeholders in the layout file to handle different rendering sections? In this case I don't see how I could render both the tree and the details pane below it, because they are interconnected. I do not think that I can use RenderBody for this case, and generating the form on the fly with jQuery will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: 1. If you're seeking a way to manage placeholders, why not use `@RenderSection("TreeSection",false)` and `@RenderSection("DetailSection",false)` ? 2. Since you're developing a SPA, I think it's better to rely on client side technology.

Comment: The issue is that they are dependent upon each other, and so render details is inside render tree. Any action on the tree will change the way details looks and behaves. Does mvc address this?

Comment: If you're using the jstree to deal with CRUD, I think it's better to use client side technology along with Web API.